# VS C#: Prompts me to resave, then refuses to open the file

Tags: visual-studio

Sometimes when I hit Save (ctrl+s) or just Save All, Visual Studio C# prompts me to resave the file I edited last. I can't save it as it is, because it already exists (and it should), and if I save it as something else, VS will prompt me for the file everytime I try to build.

If I shut down Visual Studio and try to access the file with notepad, it gives me an "access denied" message.

This is starting to piss me off since I have to redo a lot of things. Any known cause?

I'm using Windows Vista (32-bit and logged in from an administrator account).

Comment: Try to see if any other process is using the file, or if somehow the file is getting set as read only. Usually VS asks to resave the file if it's read only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is messing with the file, not Visual Studio.  Use SysInternals' Handle utility to find out what process does this.  Pop the network cable to block out co-workers with an odd sense of humor.